# Why does std::function::operator= in C++ always construct and not assign object?

Tags: c++, stl, std-function, stdany

This query is mainly based on `std::function<R(Args...) >::operator=` and `std::any::operator=`. The documentation shows that they are always implemented by constructing a new temporary object and swapping it with this object using the swap function, which is equivalent to destructing the retained object and calling the construction operation of the retained object (`T(T)`) to construct a new object. And `std::variable<Types... >::operator=` calls the assignment of the retained object (`operator=(T)`) when the LHS and RHS have the same object. The question is, why does `std::function<R(Args...) >::operator=` and `std::any::operator=` destruct the original object and construct the new object via a constructor operation, regardless of whether the new object is the same as the retained object? Wouldn't it be better to construct by assignment than by destructuring?

I have checked the documentation and searched many web pages and did not find a detailed explanation, it seems that everyone does this by convention. I would like to know the reason for using swap to handle assignment operations when implementing `std::any` and `std::function` with small object optimizations, and its best practice.

Comment: Are you aware that `std::function` has a move-assignment operator, that moves the new callable object?

Comment: There are a couple of issues: (1) the copy assignment might not exist. (2) the typical case is that the objects are different. (3) it is less exception-safe (STL aspires to be extremely exception safe... honestly, it is mostly in vain).

Comment: Presumably, "The documentation shows" means that some online source says that. It's not required by the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll skip `std::function` and focus on `std::any`.

The standard specifies that most overloads of its `operator=` must act *as if* doing a swap operation. For example,

```
any& operator=( const any& rhs );
```

> Assigns by copying the state of rhs, as if by `any(rhs).swap(*this)`

see the C++ Reference explanation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/operator%3D.

In this way the standard suggests to the implementers a possible implementation. The question is now: why's that? The answer seems to lie in the type requirements for the template parameter of `std::any`:

> The class `any` describes a type-safe container for single values of any *copy constructible* type.
> .

The property of being copy-constructible is one of the most fundamental an common properties in C++. It does not even require that values of that type be *assignable*! See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/copy_constructible for a detailed explanation of this property. Thus, `std::any::operator=` must not rely on the value assignment operator to exist, though it may use it, if it is available. It only invokes a member function `swap` of `std::any`, which is always defined.

To sum all this up, C++ tries its standard library to be as general as possible, and this is why it uses swaps for the operations you're asking about.

Finally, a simple program that uses `std::any` with a type that is not assignable, and still `std::any<X>::operator=` compiles and works:

```
#include <any>

struct X
{
  X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  X x1;
  X x2;
  std::any a = x1;
  std::any b = x2;
  a = b;
}
```

### Edit

Here's my attempt to check if gcc uses `operator=`, or whether the property of "copy-constructible" is used throughout the implementation:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  X& operator=(const X&)
  {
    std::cout << "op =\n";
    return *this;
  }
  X& operator=(const X&&)
  {
    std::cout << "move op =\n";
    return *this;
  }
  X(X&&)
  { 
    std::cout << "(&&)\n";
  };
  X(const X&)
  {
    std::cout << "(&)\n";
  }
  X()
  {
    std::cout << "()\n";
  }

//  int tab[1000];
};

int main()
{
  X x1;
  X x2;
  std::any a (x1);
  std::any b = x2;
  std::any c = 0;
  a = b;
  std::cout << sizeof(a) << "\n";
  std::cout << sizeof(c) << "\n";
}
```

This yields

```
()
()
(&)
(&)
(&)
16
16
```

irrespective of whether I uncomment the `//  int tab[1000];` line or not (to play with the small-size object optimization). This kinda shows the implementation of `std:any` needs not `operator=` of the value type in the implementation of its own `operator=`.

Comment: But he can determine whether there is an `operator=` or not, and then degenerate to using the copy construct when there is no `operator=`, can't he?

Comment: I guess yes, but I haven't managed to force gcc to use  `operator=`.